# ActiveRecord and sorting on association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a simple AR association like this:

```
Question    has_many :answers

Answer      belongs_to :question

with
  `question_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `is_accepted` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
```

in the answer. I'll have only one is_accpeted answer and am wondering if there is an easy to sort that to the top (just an order by)?

thx

Edit:
here is my Answer class:

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :question 
end
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

the answer is in your schema

```
`is_accepted` tinyint(1)
```

For many databases, ActiveRecord stores booleans `true` and `false` as `1` and `0`

so

```
question = Question.find(23)
questions.answers.order("is_accepted DESC")
```

should do what you want.

You can also add this as the default order.

```
class Question
  has_many :answers, :order => "is_accepted DESC" # rails 3
  has_many :answers, -> { order "is_accepted DESC" } # rails 4
end
```

now `question.answers` will always start with the "is_accepted" first.

Comment: where would I put this? Sorry - first time I've written a Rails app

Comment: In Rails 4 the proper way to do this would be
has_many :answers, -> { order "is_accepted DESC" }

Comment: Rails 4 the scope block `, -> { order "is_accepted DESC" }` must be immediately after association name i.e. `has_many :answers, -> { order "is_accepted DESC" }` and not after any association options `has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy, -> { order "is_accepted DESC" }`. The latter throws error `syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting =>)`.

Answer (score 2):

Add a `has_one` association on the `Question` class

```
class Question
  has_many :answers
  has_one  :accepted_answer, :class_name => "Answer", :conditions => {:is_accepted => true}
end

class Answer
  belongs_to :question
end
```

Now

```
q1.answers # returns an array of Answers objects
q1.accepted_answer # returns the accepted answer (if any)
```

To sort the answers by accepted status change your association order:

```
has_many :answers,:order => "is_accepted DESC"
```

Now

```
q1.answers # returns the accepted answer on the top
```