# Rails portfolio item not in descending order

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

I'm having some problems with a new feature I've added to my portfolio website. I have a number of portfolio entries, which I have now given categories. Everything is fine with the migration and that part works perfectly.

The only problem I am having is ordering the portfolio items in descending order in their respective categories.

Show.html.haml (for individual category)

```
-if @tag.portfolios.size > 0
  -@tag.portfolios.each do |portfolio|
   =link_to markdown(portfolio.content).first(72).html_safe, portfolio
  %br

 %p.text-right
  -if User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
=link_to 'Edit', edit_portfolio_path(portfolio)
|
=link_to 'Delete', portfolio, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }
  -else 
%br
-else
 %p Oops, I don't know what you're searching for - but it's not here!
```

Category controller

```
def index
 @tags = Tag.all
end

def show
 @portfolios = Portfolio.all( :order => "created_at DESC" )
end
```

I know it's something obvious, I just can't work out what.

Comment: you mean clicking on category, you should be able to see all portfolios under that category is DESC order. right?

Comment: When you have clicked on the category, you will see the relevant portfolio entries in descending order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you load `@portfolios` ordered, but you iterate over *`@tag.portfolios`*.
If you want `Tag` to associate `portfolios` in an ordered manner, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375680/activerecord-and-sorting-on-association):

```
class Tag
  has_many :portfolios, :order => "created_at DESC" 
end
```